# E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: ubuntu

when i tried to download something i encountered this error

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

i looked up in google to find answers for it, and nothing worked, i also found that i can use synaptic to fix broken packages but i don't have it and i can't download it. also i found out that i don't have software install...

how can i fix this error?

version: 18.04
architecture: x86_64

it happens whenever i try to download anything
but for example when i try to donwload synaptic:

```
sudo apt install synaptic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 synaptic : Depends: libxapian30 but it is not installable
            Recommends: libgtk2-perl (>= 1:1.130) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: rarian-compat but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

grep output:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:3:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:4:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:9:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:10:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic restricted multiverse universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:11:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.d.backup/danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer-bionic.list:1:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu bionic main
```

inxi -br:

```
System:    Kernel: 4.15.0-20-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Xfce 4.12.3
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Machine:   Device: laptop System: LENOVO product: 81AX v: Lenovo V330-15IKB serial: N/A
           Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: SDK0J40709 WIN serial: N/A
           UEFI [Legacy]: LENOVO v: 6SCN32WW date: 04/02/2018
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `grep -Rn --include=\*.list ^[^\#] /etc/apt/`. please.

Comment: You're asking for trouble using xenial and bionic sources, odds are apt is now confused, and trying to maintain packages that are incompatible. To start with, comment out the xenial sources, then do: apt-get upgrade then apt-get dist-upgrade and see what happens. Keeping the xenial sources in there almost certainly created a conflict that apt is not able to correct without manual intervention. Forget synaptic, you have to fix this on the command line using apt. Are you sure this is even bionic, 18-4? it looks like xenial to me.

Comment: to start, show: inxi -br  It is too difficult to see what system you are running, my guess is it's xenial that was not correctly upgraded to bionic, and bionic packages are breaking the update, which is what happens when this situation is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mixed sources: `xenial` and `bionic`.

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` as follow:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it fixed the problem :D